# Random page of followers of a Twitter user

Tags: python, api, twitter, pagination

Consider a Twitter user who has 1 million followers. I want to collect a random page of followers of this user.  Is there any way to do this? I don't want to get the list of all followers because it would exhaust my tokens.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
follower_ids = api.followers_ids(user_id, page=page_index)
```

where page_index is a random page.

Thanks.

Comment: Top tip: if the question part of your question is *"any ideas?"*, you need to do more research.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show), you can get the amount of followers from a user, e.g. `twitterdev`:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=twitterdev
```

This returns, amongst other things, `followers_count`:

```
{
  ...
  "followers_count": 143916,
  ...
}
```

From there you can work out how which pages the random followers are on.

Just to be clear, I've never used twitter, or the API, and have just searched for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can select for example 20 ids from all ids like this:

```
SCREEN_NAME= "the_user_name"
followersIds = api.followers_ids(SCREEN_NAME)

print followersIds[:20]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't want to expend my tokens, considering I have a large number of users each of which has a great number of followers!